# Extract only the first 10 lines of a csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have csv file and want to output a new csv file, that only contains the first 10 lines form the original one.
I've so far only found code to delete single lines or lines that contain a certain word. Its probably a 15 character one-liner, but I am not sure how to approach this, any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't expect you to write code, just the right command would help me out.

Answer (score 78):

```
Get-Content "C:\start.csv" | select -First 10 | Out-File "C:\stop.csv"
```

That did it

Comment: This is also an answer but depending on how big the file is the answer using `-Head 10` would be more efficient since it does not have to read the entire file.

Comment: Not sure what version you're using, but as of version 2.0, I get a message that says _Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Head'._

Comment: For powershell 2 go with emekm's answer and use "-TotalCount" parameter on "Get-Content" cmdlet.

Comment: I don't think this reads the entire file, as it was instantaneous to run with a 9GB file (PowerShell 5.1). I guess C#'s `IEnumerable` classes (or something with a similar behaviour) are being used behind the scenes for all these commands and pipe operators.

Answer (score 67):

```
Get-Content in.csv -Head 10 > out.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! Super fast and elegant!

Comment: To those confused by the several answers, `-Head`, `-TotalCount` and `-First` are aliases for the same flag.

Answer (score 25):

Using -TotalCount parameter is recommended. Especially, if you have a big CSV file.
By this way, you will only read the first 10 lines of your CSV file instead of reading all lines, selecting the first 10 lines and extracting them.

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Test.csv -TotalCount 3 | Out-File C:\Temp\Test10lines.csv
```

This works in Powershell 2 onwards.

Comment: What would be the Linux equivalent ?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Pulls schema from 1.5gb file in 3 seconds. Works as advertised.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica: The Linux equivalent would be `head -n 10 Test.csv > Test10lines.csv`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
(Get-Content yourfile.csv)[0 .. 11]>outputfile.csv
```

Be sure to include the header row or you could run into issues. You can also change the numbers to get whatever rows you want. The first and head flags did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Windows PowerShell

```
Get-Content -First 10 'C:\Users\jason\Desktop\big_file.csv'
```