# How to split large csv file with same header using php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, split

I have big csv file about 5gb.I want to split it into small files with header. I tried example given on stackoverflow but due php memory limit its not working fully and also it doesnt add header to each file and how to get only headers of csv?

Comment: An CSV has just one header! If not, you have invalid csv data. So if you have only one header then read the file line by line (fopen(),fread()), collect the first line as header. And while reading the next line write it directly into a new file (fwrite()), but dont forget the collected header as first line. IF X-lines are written, close and open the next file for write.  No `memory limit` is given here, bcause of the use of fread() and fwrite().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the following steps:

1)
First if the file contain the header then you can copy fewer lines to next csv file with following command:
Get-Content "C:\start.csv" | select -First 10 | Out-File "C:\stop.csv"

reference link: [toSelectFirstFewLinesOfCSVFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908638/extract-only-the-first-10-lines-of-a-csv-file-in-powershell)

2) after that create table accordingly.

3) Use query to load csv data to that table (for bulk load use LOAD DATA INFILE command)

4) prepare shell script for this and run through command, which can run for longer time.

(Note: you can set SET net_read_timeout = 99999;SET net_write_timeout = 99999; these connections for longer MySql connection.)

5) call the shell script.

This should work.

Comment: actually my purpose is to load this csv file into mysql but due to file size i cant load it.please tell me how to get just header of csv file?

Comment: are you using linux system?

Comment: I am on linux shared hosting.

Comment: you can use mentioned steps. let me know, if it worked or if you faced any issue.