# How does powershell lazily evaluate this statement?

Tags: powershell

I was searching for a way to to read only the first few lines of a csv file and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908638/extract-only-the-first-10-lines-of-a-csv-file-in-powershell). The accepted answer suggests using

```
Get-Content "C:\start.csv" | select -First 10 | Out-File "C:\stop.csv"
```

Another answers suggests using

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Test.csv -TotalCount 3
```

Because my csv is fairly large I went with the second option. It worked fine. Out of curiosity I decided to try the first option assuming I could `ctrl+c` if it took forever. I was surprised to see that it returned just as quickly.

Is it safe to use the first approach when working with large files? How does powershell achieve this?

Comment: second option is faster because there is no pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Select-Object -First n` is "safe" for large files (provided you want to read only a small number of lines, so pipeline overhead will be insignificant, else `Get-Content -TotalCount n` will be more efficient).

It works like `break` in a loop, by exiting the pipeline early, when the given number of items have been processed. Internally it throws a special exception that the PowerShell pipeline machinery recognizes.

---

Here is a demonstration that "abuses" `Select-Object` to break from a `ForEach-Object` "loop", which is not possible using normal `break` statement.

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host $_             # goes directly to console, so is ignored by Select-Object
   if( $_ -ge 3 ) { $true }  # "break" by outputting one item
} | Select-Object -First 1 | Out-Null
```

**Output:**

```text
1
2
3
```

As you can see, `Select-Object -First n` actually breaks the pipeline instead of first reading all input and then selecting only the specified number of items.

---

Another, more common use case is when you want to find only a single item in the output of a pipeline. Then it makes sense to exit from the pipeline as soon as you have found that item:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { SomeCondition } | Select-Object -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1) the Get-Content cmdlet has a parameter called -ReadCount. Their documentation states

> Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.
>
> This parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does affect the time it takes to display the content. As the value of ReadCount increases, the time it takes to return the first line increases, but the total time for the operation decreases. This can make a perceptible difference in large items.

Since `-ReadCount` defaults to 1 Get-Content effectively acts as a generator for reading a file line-by-line.

Comment: I agree with this. Also, its typically faster when you're not sending objects down the pipeline even though it may seem almost identical in time return, its usually not. The *Token Analyzer* (*lexical analyzer*) has to process each cmdlt for proper parsing before sending it to the powershell execution engine.