# Read CSV file meeting multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying to read a large CSV file, but I only need the data that meets certain conditions. R sometimes encounters memory usage errors when attempting to read very large datasets, so it would be beneficial to subset the data during the reading process.

I tried using the "read.csv.sql" function from the "sqldf" package but I am getting an error. Maybe I am writting the wrong code.

```r
library(sqldf)
x <- read.csv.sql(file = file.choose(), sep = "\t",
                  sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE 
                  (decimalLatitude < 44.52) 
                  AND (decimalLatitude > 35.42) 
                  AND ( decimalLongitude > -10.59) 
                  AND (decimalLongitude < 5.43)", 
                  eol = "/n")
```

```r
Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip)
: RS_sqlite_import:
C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\shell_GloBi\\interactions.tsv\\interactions.tsv
line 2 expected 88 columns of data but found 7 Warning message: In
file.remove(dbname) : cannot remove file
'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSG6ITY\\file269470c15b89',
reason 'Permission denied'
```

Here are the first 10 lines of my dataset:

```
sourceTaxonId   sourceTaxonIds  sourceTaxonName sourceTaxonRank sourceTaxonPathNames    sourceTaxonPathIds  sourceTaxonPathRankNames    sourceTaxonSpeciesName  sourceTaxonSpeciesId    sourceTaxonGenusName    sourceTaxonGenusId  sourceTaxonFamilyName   sourceTaxonFamilyId sourceTaxonOrderName    sourceTaxonOrderId  sourceTaxonClassName    sourceTaxonClassId  sourceTaxonPhylumName   sourceTaxonPhylumId sourceTaxonKingdomName  sourceTaxonKingdomId    sourceId    sourceOccurrenceId  sourceInstitutionCode   sourceCollectionCode    sourceCatalogNumber sourceBasisOfRecordId   sourceBasisOfRecordName sourceLifeStageId   sourceLifeStageName sourceBodyPartId    sourceBodyPartName  sourcePhysiologicalStateId  sourcePhysiologicalStateName    sourceSexId sourceSexName   interactionTypeName interactionTypeId   targetTaxonId   targetTaxonIds  targetTaxonName targetTaxonRank targetTaxonPathNames    targetTaxonPathIds  targetTaxonPathRankNames    targetTaxonSpeciesName  targetTaxonSpeciesId    targetTaxonGenusName    targetTaxonGenusId  targetTaxonFamilyName   targetTaxonFamilyId targetTaxonOrderName    targetTaxonOrderId  targetTaxonClassName    targetTaxonClassId  targetTaxonPhylumName   targetTaxonPhylumId targetTaxonKingdomName  targetTaxonKingdomId    targetId    targetOccurrenceId  targetInstitutionCode   targetCollectionCode    targetCatalogNumber targetBasisOfRecordId   targetBasisOfRecordName targetLifeStageId   targetLifeStageName targetBodyPartId    targetBodyPartName  targetPhysiologicalStateId  targetPhysiologicalStateName    targetSexId targetSexName   decimalLatitude decimalLongitude    localityId  localityName    eventDateUnixEpoch  argumentTypeId  referenceCitation   referenceDoi    referenceUrl    sourceCitation  sourceNamespace sourceArchiveURI    sourceDOI   sourceLastSeenAtUnixEpoch
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419522    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:4402 | GBIF:2299079 | IRMNG:10603356 | ITIS:72135 | NCBI:658865 | WORMS:419522 Cerithium lutosum   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda | [unassigned] Caenogastropoda | Cerithioidea | Cerithiidae | Cerithiinae | Cerithium | Cerithium lutosum    WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382204 | WORMS:14769 | WORMS:128 | WORMS:225178 | WORMS:137760 | WORMS:419522   superdomain | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species  Cerithium lutosum   WORMS:419522    Cerithium   WORMS:137760    Cerithiidae WORMS:128   [unassigned] Caenogastropoda    WORMS:382204    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             20.2019 -91.9759    GEONAMES:3532759    Arrecife Cayo Arcas 1461542400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003101   male organism                           commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419521    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:4397 | GBIF:2299069 | INAT_TAXON:253950 | IRMNG:11112032 | ITIS:72126 | NCBI:145870 | WORMS:419521 Cerithium eburneum  species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda |  | Cerithioidea | Cerithiidae | Cerithiinae | Cerithium | Cerithium eburneum   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382204 | WORMS:14769 | WORMS:128 | WORMS:225178 | WORMS:137760 | WORMS:419521   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Cerithium eburneum  WORMS:419521    Cerithium   WORMS:137760    Cerithiidae WORMS:128       WORMS:382204    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             22.4175 -89.7406    GEONAMES:3533115    Arrecife Alacranes  1463875200000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:368299    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26687 | GBIF:2224474 | IRMNG:11133226 | ITIS:98166 | NCBI:370536 | WORMS:368299 | doi:10.11646/zootaxa.4712.3.1 | doi:10.5281/zenodo.178168 | http://taxon-concept.plazi.org/id/Animalia/Paguristes_tortugae_Schmitt_1933 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/E218B402FFE45163FF73FF194F92C8EC | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/F07687C5FF96D270FF50FB4FFCFB8AD2    Paguristes tortugae species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Paguristes | Paguristes tortugae   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106844 | WORMS:368299    superdomain | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species    Paguristes tortugae WORMS:368299    Paguristes  WORMS:106844    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:413407    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:1877 | GBIF:5190359 | INAT_TAXON:504312 | IRMNG:11209155 | ITIS:70116 | NCBI:335784 | WORMS:413407 Lithopoma americanum    species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Vetigastropoda | Trochida | Trochoidea | Turbinidae | Turbininae | Lithopoma | Lithopoma americanum  WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:156485 | WORMS:1052448 | WORMS:156489 | WORMS:503 | WORMS:225151 | WORMS:240760 | WORMS:413407 superdomain | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species  Lithopoma americanum    WORMS:413407    Lithopoma   WORMS:240760    Turbinidae  WORMS:503   Trochida    WORMS:1052448   Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             22.3921 -89.6678    GEONAMES:3533115    Arrecife Alacranes  1464048000000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003101   male organism                           commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419505    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:1829 | GBIF:5189974 | INAT_TAXON:254234 | IRMNG:10240004 | ITIS:70168 | NCBI:537792 | WORMS:419505 Nerita tessellata   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Neritimorpha | Cycloneritida | Neritoidea | Neritidae | Neritinae | Nerita | Nerita tessellata   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:156484 | WORMS:1054475 | WORMS:196314 | WORMS:13588 | WORMS:411638 | WORMS:138254 | WORMS:419505   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Nerita tessellata   WORMS:419505    Nerita  WORMS:138254    Neritidae   WORMS:13588 Cycloneritida   WORMS:1054475   Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             18.4197 -87.7617    GEONAMES:9291830    R�o Huach, Mahahual, Quitana Roo    1456790400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003101   male organism                           commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419569    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:1840 | GBIF:2301192 | IRMNG:10219189 | ITIS:568346 | NCBI:197005 | WORMS:419569    Tectarius antonii   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda | Littorinimorpha | Littorinoidea | Littorinidae | Littorininae | Tectarius | Tectarius antonii  WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382213 | WORMS:14766 | WORMS:119 | WORMS:153707 | WORMS:204037 | WORMS:419569   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Tectarius antonii   WORMS:419569    Tectarius   WORMS:204037    Littorinidae    WORMS:119   Littorinimorpha WORMS:382213    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             18.4197 -87.7617    GEONAMES:9291830    R?�o Huach, Mahahual, Quitana Roo   1456790400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:368299    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26687 | GBIF:2224474 | IRMNG:11133226 | ITIS:98166 | NCBI:370536 | WORMS:368299 | doi:10.11646/zootaxa.4712.3.1 | doi:10.5281/zenodo.178168 | http://taxon-concept.plazi.org/id/Animalia/Paguristes_tortugae_Schmitt_1933 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/E218B402FFE45163FF73FF194F92C8EC | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/F07687C5FF96D270FF50FB4FFCFB8AD2    Paguristes tortugae species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Paguristes | Paguristes tortugae   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106844 | WORMS:368299    superdomain | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species    Paguristes tortugae WORMS:368299    Paguristes  WORMS:106844    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:208599    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:5324 | GBIF:2305751 | IRMNG:10533196 | IRMNG:11336370 | ITIS:73710 | NCBI:2019505 | WORMS:208599   Columbella mercatoria   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda | Neogastropoda | Buccinoidea | Columbellidae | Columbella | Columbella mercatoria   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:146 | WORMS:382214 | WORMS:23009 | WORMS:137803 | WORMS:208599  null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | genus | species Columbella mercatoria   WORMS:208599    Columbella  WORMS:137803    Columbellidae   WORMS:23009 Neogastropoda   WORMS:146   Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             21.3483 -90.1461    GEONAMES:3516634    Arrecife Bajo de 10 1556150400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419505    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:1829 | GBIF:5189974 | INAT_TAXON:254234 | IRMNG:10240004 | ITIS:70168 | NCBI:537792 | WORMS:419505 Nerita tessellata   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Neritimorpha | Cycloneritida | Neritoidea | Neritidae | Neritinae | Nerita | Nerita tessellata   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:156484 | WORMS:1054475 | WORMS:196314 | WORMS:13588 | WORMS:411638 | WORMS:138254 | WORMS:419505   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Nerita tessellata   WORMS:419505    Nerita  WORMS:138254    Neritidae   WORMS:13588 Cycloneritida   WORMS:1054475   Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             18.4197 -87.7617    GEONAMES:9291830    R�o Huach, Mahahual, Quitana Roo    1456790400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419522    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:4402 | GBIF:2299079 | IRMNG:10603356 | ITIS:72135 | NCBI:658865 | WORMS:419522 Cerithium lutosum   species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda | [unassigned] Caenogastropoda | Cerithioidea | Cerithiidae | Cerithiinae | Cerithium | Cerithium lutosum    WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382204 | WORMS:14769 | WORMS:128 | WORMS:225178 | WORMS:137760 | WORMS:419522   superdomain | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species  Cerithium lutosum   WORMS:419522    Cerithium   WORMS:137760    Cerithiidae WORMS:128   [unassigned] Caenogastropoda    WORMS:382204    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             20.2036 -91.9761    GEONAMES:3532759    Arrecife Cayo Arcas 1451606400000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003101   male organism                           commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419557    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:1166 | GBIF:2301143 | INAT_TAXON:493347 | IRMNG:10214992 | ITIS:567330 | NCBI:197001 | WORMS:419557    Cenchritis muricatus    species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda | Littorinimorpha | Littorinoidea | Littorinidae | Littorininae | Cenchritis | Cenchritis muricatus  WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382213 | WORMS:14766 | WORMS:119 | WORMS:153707 | WORMS:415176 | WORMS:419557   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Cenchritis muricatus    WORMS:419557    Cenchritis  WORMS:415176    Littorinidae    WORMS:119   Littorinimorpha WORMS:382213    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             18.5392 -87.7412    GEONAMES:9291830    Punta Piedra, Mahahual, Quitana Roo 1457827200000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
WORMS:367527    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:26711 | GBIF:2224451 | IRMNG:10239265 | ITIS:98191 | NCBI:1127465 | WORMS:367527 | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/03A787D9FFDDDF3AFF73FAE7784EB23D | http://treatment.plazi.org/id/87748C32F81EF408CE89FC76FD44F623 Clibanarius tricolor    species Biota | Animalia | Arthropoda | Crustacea | Multicrustacea | Malacostraca | Eumalacostraca | Eucarida | Decapoda | Pleocyemata | Anomura | Paguroidea | Diogenidae | Clibanarius | Clibanarius tricolor WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:1065 | WORMS:1066 | WORMS:845959 | WORMS:1071 | WORMS:1086 | WORMS:1089 | WORMS:1130 | WORMS:106670 | WORMS:106671 | WORMS:106687 | WORMS:106736 | WORMS:106841 | WORMS:367527    null | kingdom | phylum | subphylum | superclass | class | subclass | superorder | order | suborder | infraorder | superfamily | family | genus | species   Clibanarius tricolor    WORMS:367527    Clibanarius WORMS:106841    Diogenidae  WORMS:106736    Decapoda    WORMS:1130  Malacostraca    WORMS:1071  Arthropoda  WORMS:1065  Animalia    WORMS:2                             http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0003100   female organism                         commensalistOf  http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002441   WORMS:419521    FBC:SLB:SpecCode:4397 | GBIF:2299069 | INAT_TAXON:253950 | IRMNG:11112032 | ITIS:72126 | NCBI:145870 | WORMS:419521 Cerithium eburneum  species Biota | Animalia | Mollusca | Gastropoda | Caenogastropoda |  | Cerithioidea | Cerithiidae | Cerithiinae | Cerithium | Cerithium eburneum   WORMS:1 | WORMS:2 | WORMS:51 | WORMS:101 | WORMS:224570 | WORMS:382204 | WORMS:14769 | WORMS:128 | WORMS:225178 | WORMS:137760 | WORMS:419521   null | kingdom | phylum | class | subclass | order | superfamily | family | subfamily | genus | species Cerithium eburneum  WORMS:419521    Cerithium   WORMS:137760    Cerithiidae WORMS:128       WORMS:382204    Gastropoda  WORMS:101   Mollusca    WORMS:51    Animalia    WORMS:2                                                             22.4175 -89.7406    GEONAMES:3533115    Arrecife Alacranes  1463875200000   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/support  Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.. Accessed at <https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip> on 17 Nov 2021.           Cervantes-Campero G and Simões N (2020). Use of shells (Mollusca) by hermit crabs (Paguroidea) from the Southern Gulf of Mexico and the Caribbean Sea.  BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions https://zenodo.org/record/3901657/files/BDMYRepository/Paguroidea-Mollusca-Interactions-1.1.zip 10.5281/zenodo.3901657  2021-11-12T23:11:25.778Z
```

Comment: You might also want to use the lazy loading feature of the R package [vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/)

Comment: Seerms that you don't own the file `file269470c15b89`. Do you have Admin rights to remove it manually?

Comment: Are you sure that the columns are tab separated and not comma separated? The problem is in the data file  so we can't debug ithe code.

Comment: Please post a sample of data for [mcve]. On Windows, consider PowerShell's [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3) to extract first n lines and save to file with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913399/1422451). Then paste text content here.

Comment: In addition to `vroom`, I've found `arrow::read_csv_arrow` to be rather good, and if you're accustomed to dplyr syntax, it's a "lazy" pipe until you `%>% collect()` the data into the R environment.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eladio! I suspect that the "permission" problem is a red herring (for this question at least). Having the first few lines of the file as a sample would be helpful, as we can at best speculate about its contents and the error you're getting. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (as you've done, nice!) and sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., the raw contents of the top 5 or so lines from the file, into a [code block]). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I just added the first 10 lines of my dataset to the body of the question. When using a file with these 10 lines of data, I did not receive any errors and I obtained an object with the correct column names, but 0 observations since no rows met the conditions. Perhaps there is an issue with the entire dataset, but I am unsure.

Comment: Try using the `skip` argument in `read.csv` -- read a chunk, filter&process, delete the input blob, read the next chunk, etc.

Comment: The eol of `/n` is wrong.  You want `\n` or possibly `\r\n` depending on your file.